# Golang import based on config variable

Tags: go

I'm currently in the process of still learning go but I recently got to a point where in one of my tests I wanted to create a quick backup application that will reference a config file and switch what "plugin" to use for the backup.  So what I got to at this point is to create (as example, written from my head and syntax may be incorrect):

```
type BackupStorage interface{
   Put (d []byte) (n int, err Error)
   Get (l []byte) (d []byte, err Error)
}
```

At this point I would assume I should use reflection to switch on the type and return the specific backup function, although that does not seem right.

The second alternative I came to was to still use my BackupStorage interface and create "plugin" packages to dictate which import will be used, but how do I switch that then based on a config file variable.  And I'd like to do this because some stuff on one machine may backup only to s3 where as others may backup to both s3 and google drive etc.

With the basic example above what I have in mind is this:
Implement 2 BackupStorage "plugins" (Google Drive / S3) with the flexibility to add more at any time, but have my code be generic enough to execute on whatever storage backend is selected in config files.

As I mentioned above I'm still learning and any explanations would be appreciated or examples on how to accomplish this.  I don't mind the "your doing it wrong" as long as there is a proper explanation on why it's wrong and how to do it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea to start, implement everything you need via an interface, and then you can plug in any concrete backup "plugin" that implements that interface.

Once you can run your backup via an interface, you can simply assign an instance of the backend you want based on whatever conditions you set.

```
var storage Backupper

type Backupper interface {
    Backup()
}

type GDrive struct {
    config string
}

func (g *GDrive) Backup() {
    fmt.Println("Doing backup to Google Drive")
}

func main() {
    storage = &GDrive{}
    storage.Backup()
}
```

Or with multiple options: http://play.golang.org/p/RlmXjf55Yh